# How is "over-the-top" related to online streaming?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I know OTT means online content business, but why is "over the top" linguistically used? Literally I don't see much connection.

Comment: Do you have an actual sentence or, better yet, a reference? [*Over the top*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over%20the%20top) is an adjective that means "extremely or excessively flamboyant or outrageous," and it can refer to any number of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Over the top" is used about media service providers who make their products (TV programmes, films, etc) available to the viewer over the Internet without involving intermediaries such as TV networks, internet service providers, or cable TV providers. This by-passing of intermediaries is being likened to flying over an obstacle. Sometimes, in business or work, avoiding an intermediary person or organisation is called "going over their head". OTT providers include Netflix, Amazon Video, Hulu, etc.

[Over the top media services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-top_media_services)